# Saving python stdout to a variable works in python shell but not as a script

Tags: python, variables, yaml, stdout

I'm trying to save stdout to a variable in python. My current solution works fine in a python shell, but when ran as a script it errors. Here is my current test code:

```
    import yaml
    import sys
    from slackclient import SlackClient
    from io import StringIO  # Python3
    slack_token = "SOME TOKEN HERE"
    sc = SlackClient(slack_token)
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    result = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = result
    row_message = '[{"title": "Test", "pretext": "this is an example         message!", "text": "Super Awesome Test!"}]'
    sc.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel="#channel_name",
        username="My User",
        icon_url="http://some.url.here/",
        attachments=row_message
    )
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    result_string = result.getvalue()
    example = yaml.load(result_string)['ts']
    print(example)
```

My output in the python shell is what i expect:

```
    >>> print(example)
    1489460593.207577
    >>>
```

But when I save the code and run it as a script:

```
    # ./test 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./test", line 22, in <module>
        example = yaml.load(result_string)['ts']
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Could anyone enlighten me as to why this works in the python shell but not as a script? What can I try to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is in stdout because nothing is being printed. Probably Slack returns the string, not prints it. It gets printed in the interpreter because thats what the interpreter does to results that don't get saved somewhere. If you remove the stdout swap, what happens? Does the value get printed? My guess is not. Just save it directly into a variable and stop messing with stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @zstewart, you were correct. I was just overcomplicating it. Here is what I am doing instead.

```
        response = sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel="#channel", username="username", icon_url="http://some.url.here", attachments=row_message)
        thread_val_list = [ val for key,val in response.items() if key=='ts' ]
        thread_val = "".join(thread_val_list)
```